# Call to undefined function XML_unserialize()

Tags: php, html, yahoo

I'm making search engine in php for ranking my site by Yahoo API key.
I have just got an error like this:

> `Fatal error: Call to undefined function XML_unserialize() in E:\wamp\www\Yahoo\search.php on line 113`

What should I do?

Comment: It probably means there's an error in your search.php script, but my telepathy is playing up today

Comment: What, pray tell, is on line 113 of E:\wamp\www\Yahoo\search.php?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like an XML library you're including was not properly included, so this function was not found when it was called.

Try running your code with

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

at the top of the script, and it will show all warnings. This should tell you if there were any failures to find include files.

Answer (score 0):

Few things:

1. Maybe you haven't included the file, where the XML_unserialize() function is.
2. You have a typo in the function name.